# Rewriting file name on download (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache2

I have a folder where the uploads are saved (/upload/0/)

When the file is uploaded, the program automatically renames the file for instance file1.jpg is uploaded as qzRTRWW.

How can I rename automatically that file (not matter of the name) but I want to add an extension to it (jpg).

I have tested using a rewrite rule like this (in .htaccess)

RewriteRule /upload/(.*).jpeg  $1  [L]

but without success.

I have testes in apache an lighttpd too.

Anyone ?

thanks a lot